# Add Angular material chips to input box

Tags: angular, angular-material

Kind of new to Angular and I have spent about a week reading the documentation but I still can't work this out. If we have a list of Angular Material chips like the code below

```
<input type="text" name="fname" size=35>
<p></p>
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let dt of chips">{{dt}}</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip >One fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Two fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip >Primary fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip >Accent fish</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

How can I make it when I click a tag to add that tag to the input box in order to formulate a query with a combination of tags? Appreciate and thankful for any help.

Comment: See this example code from material team: https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvvkqgrrebo?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts

Comment: Not quite. I've seen that before. I was thinking the tags will be added to the input box after I select them from a predefined list. I cannot seem to find an example of something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer by playing around with different examples. Essentially you need two lists, one to hold the chips you want the user to select and one that holds the selected chips and shows them at the input box.

When the user selects a chip, you get the chip value from the click event and you add it to the list. The rest is easy because it gets handled by Angular's properties and directives.

You can see more details in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-chips-addedtoinput)

Looking forward for any feedback on the code and improvements.

Comment: I know this is from 3 years ago but if we want to add some text and between texts, have some chipses too?